# Pass LuisResult to child dialog

Tags: botframework

I have a root dialog, a LuisDialog, from which I am calling some child dialogs, as follows

```
    [LuisModel("8869ccea-7c5f-4cce-8639-64bbc7ecd62b", "c5835534ed7746449356c62dcdf48fde")]
[Serializable]
public class DefaultDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{

    [LuisIntent("showIncidents")]
    public async Task ShowIncidents(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> _message, LuisResult result)
    {
        var message = await _message;
        await context.Forward(new ShowIncident(), ResumeAfter,message,CancellationToken.None);
    }

    [LuisIntent("CreateIncident")]
    public async Task CreateIncident(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        //context.Call(new CreateIncident(), ResumeAfter);
        context.Call(new CreateIncident(), ResumeAfter);
    }
```

When I call the "ShowIncident()" dialiog, i'd like to forward the LuisResult rather than message, because I need the entities from the LuisResult in the child dialog. So i tried calling the child dialog with the following code:

```
await context.Forward(new ShowIncident(), ResumeAfter,result,CancellationToken.None);
```

I tried implementing my "ShowIncident" dialog as follows:

```
    [Serializable]
public class ShowIncident : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<LuisResult> _result)
    {
        var result = await _result;
         // Get and post Incidents
         Incidents incidents = await ServiceNow.GetIncidentsAsync();
         await context.PostAsync(incidents.toText());
    }
}
```

This throws an error, which I assume is because `IAwaitable<LuisResult>` has to be `IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>`. 
I realize I could use several workarounds, like positing the entities as a message or using a public static class to define the incidents. But what would be the 'proper way'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David Manton is correct about LuisResult being non-serializable. Your best bet there is to extract the parts you need into your own serializable object and pass that to your dialog constructor.

However, he is incorrect about dependency injection with the given answer.
In your AutoFac module, or where you're executing your registrations you would register your dialog like this:

```
builder.Register((c, p) => new ShowIncident (p.Named<string("luisResult"))).InstancePerDependency();
```

Then, when you want to call ShowIncident, you resolve for the dialog like this:

```
            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
            {
                context.Call(scope.Resolve<ShowIncident>(new NamedParameter("luisResult", luisResult)), ResumeAfterIncidentDialog);
            }
```

This is a common method in Autofac when your object has one or more parameters that can only be resolved at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

Add a constructor to `ShowIncident`

```
public class ShowIncident : IDialog<object>
{
       private LuisResult _luisResult;
       public ShowIncident(LuisResult luisResult) 
       {
         _luisResult = _luisResult;
       }

       public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity)
       { //....
```

and call it like this context.Call(new `CreateIncident(result), ResumeAfter)`;

Comment: Did you actually mean "Add a constructor to `ShowIncident`" instead? @Sergey

Comment: @superjos yes, thanks for noticing it. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is problematic because the LuisResult is not serializable.  This may cause your dialog to fail at runtime.

There are two options, you could set it in the constructor, however this stops you using dialogs with dependency injection.

Another option is to add a property and set the LuisResult value after the dialog has been constructed, this is then compatible with using dependency injection.

However you choose to do this you'll need something like the following

```
[NonSerialized]
private LuisResult _luisData;
public LuisResult LuisData {
    get => _luisData;
    set => _luisData = value;
}
```

This is to make sure you don't create run time errors.